# Difference between "due to" and "on account of"

Tags: difference

What's difference between the following words:

> "due to"

AND

> "on account of"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Our basement flooded due to the rain.
>   We rescheduled the concert on account of the rain.

There is (subtle) difference between those two sentences.

The rain actually *caused* the flooding of our basement. However, the rain did not physically influence the planning of the concert: *we* rescheduled it, not the rain.

In many cases, the difference will be so subtle that even native speakers may substitute one for the other.In general, though, I would advise to use *on account of* when an action or decision is *influenced by* something, and *due to* when something is *caused by* something.

Comment: It seems to me your distinction arises purely from the different context, since you could swap ***due to / on account of*** between those two examples. As [BBC Learning English](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv56.shtml) says of ***Due to, owing to, on account of, because of***: *They are all prepositions used with noun phrases and are often used interchangeably.*

Comment: I did mention they are often used interchangeably. However, saying that, say, a street was closed off _due_ to a demonstration would seem to give me the idea that demonstrators blocked a road, whereas a closed-off street _on account of a demonstration_ would make be think the street was closed off pre-emptively by the authorities, knowing a demonstration was going to take place. But it's very well possible that I am seeing a distinction that is not widely shared, or that might not even exist.

Comment: [Due to in the sense ‘because of’, as in he had to retire due to an injury, has been condemned as incorrect on the grounds that due is an adjective and should not be used as a preposition; owing to is often recommended as a better alternative. However, the prepositional use, first recorded at the end of the 19th century, is now common in all types of literature and is regarded as part of standard English.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/due) But I confess I can't easily tell if your distinction reflects that largely abandoned perspective.

Comment: I think the distinction has a different origin, @FumbleFingers.  The rain flooded the basement.  No one took the rain into account.  The rain did not reschedule the concert.  We took the rain into account when we rescheduled.  The difference that oerkelens finds between "due to the demonstration" and "on account of the demonstration" is likely whether someone took the demonstration into account.

Answer (score 1):

Broadly, they mean the same. Most of the dictionaries I searched on agree.

> [Because of](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/because+of?show=0&t=1417436393) = [due to](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/due%20to) = [on account of](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/on+account+of)

However, the context matters. In most cases, you can interchange them keeping the structure of the sentence in mind.

Similar question is [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/118973/because-of-vs-on-account-of).